Неправильно читаются поля объектов из словаря std::map
Изучая возможности С++ я сделал код в котором для примера определяю класс Bar с парой полей и "класс-менеджер" в котором есть vector<Bar> для хранения объектов и массив map<int, Bar*>, в котором храню указатели на те-же объекты проиндексированный по одному из полей. Идея в том что при добавлении нового объекта Bar в вектор - я записываю указатель на него в map чтобы получить доступ к этим объектам сразу по полю-индексу. Для простоты поле-индекс в виде простого int. Добавляю несколько элементов и распечатываю что получилось:
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

class Bar {
public:
    const int x;
    const char key;

    Bar(int p_x, char p_key): x(p_x), key(p_key) {}

    void print() {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << this << " x:" << x << " key: " << key  <<"" << std::endl;
    }
};

class BarManager {
protected:
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
    std::map<int, Bar*> bars_map;
public:

    void add_bar(int x, char key)
    {
        Bar bar = Bar(x, key);
        bars.push_back(bar);
        Bar* bar_ptr = &bars.back();
        bars_map[x] = bar_ptr;
    }

    void print_bars()
    {
        for (Bar& bar: bars) {
            bar.print();
        }
    }

    void print_map()
    {
        for(const auto pair : bars_map) {
            int index = pair.first;
            const Bar* bar_ptr = pair.second;
            std::cout << "index:" << index << " - " << " x:" << bar_ptr->x << " key:" << bar_ptr->key << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BarManager bar_mgr;

    bar_mgr.add_bar(0, 'a');
    bar_mgr.add_bar(0, 'b');
    bar_mgr.add_bar(1, 'c');
    bar_mgr.add_bar(2, 'd');
    bar_mgr.add_bar(3, 'e');
    bar_mgr.add_bar(0, 'x');

    bar_mgr.print_bars();
    std::cout << "==================================================" << std::endl;
    bar_mgr.print_map();

    return 0;
}


И тут у меня выходит все вроде хорошо:
Bar: 0x5b954c970fe0 x:0 key: a
Bar: 0x5b954c970fe8 x:0 key: b
Bar: 0x5b954c970ff0 x:1 key: c
Bar: 0x5b954c970ff8 x:2 key: d
Bar: 0x5b954c971000 x:3 key: e
Bar: 0x5b954c971008 x:0 key: x
==================================================
index:0 -  x:0 key:x
index:1 -  x:1 key:c
index:2 -  x:2 key:d
index:3 -  x:3 key:e

Но если я добавляю поле в класс Bar, например:
class Bar {
public:
    const int x;
    int y = 1;
    const char key;

    Bar(int p_x, char p_key): x(p_x), key(p_key) {}

    void print() {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << this << " x:" << x << " key: " << key  <<"" << std::endl;
    }
};

то получаю неверные значения у полей Bar из map
Bar: 0x58024f3d3ff0 x:0 key: a
Bar: 0x58024f3d3ffc x:0 key: b
Bar: 0x58024f3d4008 x:1 key: c
Bar: 0x58024f3d4014 x:2 key: d
Bar: 0x58024f3d4020 x:3 key: e
Bar: 0x58024f3d402c x:0 key: x
==================================================
index:0 -  x:0 key:x
index:1 -  x:0 key:
index:2 -  x:2 key:
index:3 -  x:3 key:e

Пытаюсь понять в чем тут проблема.

Во-первых, элементы с одинаковыми x у вас перезаписываются, остается только один, последний. Так что индексацией это назвать трудно... Во-вторых, операция bars.push_back(bar); может изменить адреса всех объектов, которые уже находятся в векторе. В-третьих :) - мне воспроизвести ваши неприятности не удалось. На таком небольшом количестве данных инвалидация у меня не произошла. У вас какой компилятор? Как вариант: попробуйте вектор не элементов, а указателей на элементы (только потом не забудьте их освободить; или используйте умные указатели).

После добавления в вектор может произойти перераспределение памяти, что инвалидирует старые указатели. А значит значения в map начинают указывать на мусор.

Большое спасибо за ответы, это поведение вектора ускользнуло от моего внимания. @Harry да я знаю что там идет перезапись, но это просто учебный эксперимент поэтому это пока не важно, в дальнейшем я хотел еще и удалять из вектора те объекты. которые перезаписываются.
Получается в векторе хранить объекты нецелесообразно, из вариантов вижу - выделять под объекты память через new и хранить указатели как в первом комментарии или сделать статичный массив через [], но статичный массив придется заполнять какими-то пустыми фейк-объектами.
Компилятор gcc 11.

Почему - статический массив? Чем не нравится предложенный мной вариант хранить вектор указателей (значения-то указателей при переносе не изменятся) или умных указателей?

Я рассматривал оба варианта и в простом массиве и через указатели, но тогда под объекты надо выделять память в куче, мне казалось что может быть мне этого не нужно и достаточно переменной в стэке. В итоге я уже реализовал вариант с указателями на объекты в куче и всё отлично работает.

Но почему вы не храните в словаре индексы объектов в векторе? Это просто, безопасно, не требует размещать объекты в куче.

Разве удаление объектов из середины вектора не будет менять индексы последующих?
